# kubernetes ImagePullBackOff

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

kubectl run docapp --image=docapp:v1 --port=8080

After deploying nodejs into kubernetes, im getting ImagePullBackOff, Please suggest the solutions.
I have attached snapshot below...

[imagepullbackoff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TwrO.png)

[minikube dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnJDq.png)

Answer (score 3):

There is no image named "docapp" in official namespace in dockerhub. If you mean this image: https://hub.docker.com/r/alexkott/docapp/ you need to specify in your image the namespace so it will be: alexkott/docapp